# Need help making threads in discord.py command

Tags: python, python-3.x, for-loop, discord, discord.py

I am trying to make this command to run in threads (which would make it faster) in my discord bot but it is not working out to well. This is is the command code

```py
@Astro.command()
async def delchannels(ctx):
    if isinstance(ctx.message.channel, discord.DMChannel) or isinstance(ctx.message.channel, discord.GroupChannel):
        await ctx.message.delete
        await ctx.send("You can't use this command in DMs or GCs", delete_after=3)
    else:
        await ctx.message.delete()
        for channel in list(ctx.guild.channels):
            try:
                await channel.delete()
            except:
                return
```

Comment: Why would you want it to run in separated threats?

Comment: @ŁukaszKwieciński I want to make it faster

Comment: It's not really a good idea mixing asyncio and threading, I also wouldn't recommend sending the messages with `asyncio.gather` or similar because it's API abuse.